# Solving a first order non linear PDE with the method of characteristics

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

We have to find the function $u(x,y)$ for the following system:

- $u_xu_y = xy$
- $u(x,y) = y+1$ for $x=y$

Using the method of characterstics I get:

$F(x,y,u,u_x,u_y) = u_xu_y-xy = 0$

Defining $p = u_x$ and $q = u_y$ we get:

$F(x,y,u,p,q) = pq-xy = 0$

I use a parametrisation for $s = 0$:

- $x(t) = y(t)$
- $y(t) = t$
- $u(t) = t+1$

We are supposed to find p and q out of the following system:

- $F(x,y,u,p,q) = 0$
- $u_t = px_t+qy_t$

By filling in what we know we get:

- $pq-t^2 = 0$
- $p+q = 1$

I am not quite sure how to find p and q out of this system.

The characteristic differential equations are:

- $x_s = F_p = q$, for $s=0 : x=t$
- $y_s = F_q = p$, for $s=0 : y=t$
- $u_s = pF_p+qF_q = 2pq$, for $s=0 : u=t+1$
- $p_s=-F_x-pF_u = y$, for $s=0 : p= ?$
- $q_s = -F_y-qF_u = x$, for $s=0 : q= ?$

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $u = y^2 + 1$ in the condition for $x = y$?

Comment: I am sure it is $u=y+1$ on the condition $x=y$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

Let $\begin{cases}p=x^2\\q=y^2\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_pp_x+u_qq_x=2xu_p$

$u_y=u_pp_y+u_qq_y=2yu_q$

$\therefore2xu_p2yu_q=xy$ with $u(\sqrt q,\sqrt q)=\sqrt q+1$

$u_p=\dfrac{1}{4u_q}$ with $u(q,q)=q+1$